# Why is so hard to isolate sound?

Tags: acoustics

I was thinking in a noise-canceling kennel for dogs specially during fireworks.

And I was surprised that nothing exists, recently Ford worked in something like that, but just as a prototype
https://www.curbed.com/2018/12/19/18147416/ford-dog-house-noise-canceling-soundproof
// it is using Active Noise Cancellation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_noise_control)

Why is so hard to build a box with complete sound isolation from the outside? what makes the sound so difficult to stop?

Comment: Doesn't exist or is it too expensive? There are hotels in airports (Frankfurt for example) of train stations (Tokyo), where the sound is amazingly damped.

Comment: Active damping is easiest (by far) is you can place the damper on the line between source and reciever. To damp input from many directions you need an array of recievers and if the damping is to affect a volume rather than a point you need an array of transmitters as well. The price of the hardware goes up fast, as does the complexity of the inverse problem to be approximated (in a hurry, mind you).

Comment: but what about passive noise reduction? with materials. Why is so hard to stop the sound?

Comment: @dmckee That looks like an answer. :)

Comment: Passive damping is well understood. Multiple layers of varied materials, heavy enough construction, and attention to detail in terms of cracks and voids. The people who build sound studios have it down to a science. But that is also expensive. Especially if you want to damp low frequencies.

Comment: I think the answer to the physics question "what makes the sound so difficult to stop?" is that the penetration depth always goes as 1/frequency. The EM visibile spectrum is in the THz so penetration depths are minuscule, while for the audible sound range (to humans) is from a few Hz to kHz.

Answer (score 1):

Well, passive damping as dmckee mentions is quite well understood and modelled (there is still a long way to go though). Roughly speaking, in order to attenuate low frequencies, you need very big masses. This is what makes anechoic chamber walls being so thick (in addition to all other layers, springs/dampers and absorption). This would require concrete walls of thickness up to 2 metres, or more, if you would like to achieve considerable attenuation in low to very low frequencies. On the contrary, you can more easily achieve attenuation of high frequencies with passive elements.

Now, regarding active noise control systems, these work well for low frequencies, where the wavelengths are considerably long. If you want to achieve complete destructive interference (this is the main idea behind active noise control anyway) over a wide area, it means that you should be able to exactly match the wavefield in this area. Then, reversing the polarity of the sound you create, will provide complete cancellation. This can happen with a reasonably small amount of radiators/emitters for a reasonably large area (here the term "reasonably" is very dependent on the application) only when the sound field is constant (this would be DC) or has small variations (look at dmckee's comment too). The second case is where long wavelengths come in. Having less variation for a certain area than the high frequencies (short wavelength) means that you can achieve attenuation (not complete cancellation though) in a larger area because you can match better the sound field there.

Now, if you have yet another look at the dog kennel you mention you will realise that both technologies are used. This is quite often the case in many scenarios, where active noise control is used to control/attenuate the low frequencies and passive means are used to control/attenuate the higher frequencies.

As Claudio Saspinski mentions, there are cases where very good results are achieved with even just passive elements (such as recording/mixing/mastering studios, big venues, live gig arenas, etc.). On the other hand, the kennel you cited as well as recent automotive advances are good examples where hybrid designs (both active noise control and passive attenuation) are extensively utilised. Finally, systems, where only active noise control is used, are quite rare. Some cases may be considered to be cancelling headphones (although they do have attenuation from their muffles), or specific ventilation channels where absorptive linings may not be allowed (haven't encountered such a case yet).